# Google slides API ReplaceAllShapesWithImageRequest : how to make sure the images keep the same shape?

Tags: google-slides-api

Is there a way to keep the shape when replacing the image ?

Here is what my request looks like

```
{
  "imageReplaceMethod": "CENTER_CROP",
  "containsText": {
    "text": "{{IMG_1}}"
  },
  "imageUrl": "https:// ..."
}
```

The request works and does replace the shape but my shape was round and now my picture is squared...